# Do we have to register JQuery if we want to use it in wp_enqueue_script()?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Or is it registered by default?
I am enqueuing a script with wp_enqueue_script()

```
wp_enqueue_script('validation', 'http://domain.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme/js/validation.js', array('jquery'));
```

But I get this error in the console:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`

Also do I need to put the absolute path to link my js, or can I use a relative path? Relative to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to register it but in your own js file, replace the first `$` to `jQuery`.

jQuery is loaded in [No Conflict Mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Your code here. Use $ as normal.
});
```

And if you use anonymous functions, do it like this

```
(function($) {
   // Your code here. Use $ as normal.
})(jQuery);
```

Also, you need to use relative paths.

Comment: Ahh yes thank you. But relative path to what? To the wordpress root or theme root?

Comment: @Maxwell The url to js file. The url in your example looks fine.

Comment: Why would you use relative paths? My experience is that those are nothing but trouble in WordPress context.

Comment: You want an absolute path, but use the API to output it: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/validation.js'` instead of hardcoding it.